# Gsutil not installing on amazon ec2?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil

My ec2 linux is

`Linux ip-<ip> <...>.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 14 01:17:26 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

and I am trying to install gsutil but it throws a syntax error

logs are :

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash

<many file>

google-cloud-sdk/.install/core.manifest
google-cloud-sdk/.install/.download/

/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 12, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 32, in <module>
    import setup  # pylint:disable=g-import-not-at-top
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/setup.py", line 55, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import properties
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/properties.py", line 296
    self.__sections = {section.name: section for section in sections}
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python version : Python 2.7.13
Even gcloud isn't installing 
Whats wrong?

I just want to transfer data from S3 to google bucket using cli